# Synchronize audio output on 2 Windows computers

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10, sync

I found a few questions a bit similar to this one, but none about Windows.

I want to synchronize the audio output playing on one Windows 10 computer with 1 or more computers with Windows 10 installed on the same (LAN) network.

I do not want to use a specific music player software, since I love the one I'm already using and it doesn't support this.

I thought perhaps there is some way to install an audio output device and use that to synchronize all audio output on the computer to several computers (including the one the music is being played on) - perhaps as an input to another app that can perform this kind of synchronization.

I tried to use TeamViewer remote desktop for that, which works (it transfers the remote computer's audio), but it causes a delay that causes the music not to be synchronized.

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with (other than using something analog like an FM radio transmitter or audio cables) will have some sort of delay between the master audio and the slave outputs to allow for buffering and synchronization with each other.  Expect something in the 0.1 to 2 second range.  That being said, it should be possible to get all the outputs in very close synchronization relative to each other.  Is this acceptable?

Comment: No, I'm looking for something that will be completely synchronized. Theoretically it should be possible to write code that sends the data and buffers it and only when the both computers have the data, play it on both (thus playing synced music on both computers on the expense of a slight delay on both computers).